# Redirect to external url with headers in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a web site built using ASP.NET MVC and angular 7, and I want to redirect to another web site built using WebForms.

But I don't want to passe the parameters in the URL, instead, I want to pass the parameters in headers.

Thanks in advance!

I tried the HttpClient, but I think it is not appropriate for this task.

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic blah');
    headers = headers.set('anotherHeader', 'More blah');
    this.http.request('GET', 'test.com', { headers })
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            this.res = res;
            console.log('Result:', res)
          },
          err => {
            console.log('Error', err);
            this.err = err;
          },
        );
```

Comment: If you want to help you better you must paste some code, describe more your problem, what have you tried and pass some comments if you can

Comment: You realise that parameters in GET request are in the URL?

Comment: *'I tried the HttpClient, but I think it is not appropriate for this task.'* -- Why so? Are you getting some error? Please be more specific.

Comment: From what I found on the internet HttpClient is for calling web APIs and getting results or posting data.  But what I want to achieve here is to redirect to another web site and passing the parameters in headers.